# You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave

I run the code in debug mode and realized that below error message is coming in the path error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value.

[image]

```
{
   "error": "authentication failed: Could not bind with your username/pw: LDAP Result Code 49 \"Invalid Credentials\": 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090442, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839\u0000"
}
```

But when I try to capture the value

```
(read(error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value,"application/json"))
```

in a variable throwing below error.

```
ERROR 2020-05-28 08:43:56,779 [[MuleRuntime].io.01: [proc-brain-usage-sync-batch].send-usage-data-to-brain.BLOCKING @164a6d7b] [event: 2ec6d1e1-a049-11ea-9b85-00059a3c7a00] org.mule.extension.jsonlogger.JsonLoggerExtension: Failed parsing field: content
org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("{\"error\":\"authentication failed: Could not bind with your username/pw: LD...)
  2: Name ("value")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (Time, Name)

5|  brainerror: write(error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value, "application/json") default "" 
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at write (line: 5, column: 20)
  at main (line: 5, column: 14)" evaluating expression: "output application/json ---
{
 usageMetadata: vars.usageMetadata,
 attributes: attributes,
 brainerror: write(error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value, "application/json") default "" 
}".
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException: You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("{\"error\":\"authentication failed: Could not bind with your username/pw: LD...)
  2: Name ("value")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (Time, Name)

5|  brainerror: write(error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value, "application/json") default "" 
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can i capture the value in the path 'error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value' the way we capture error.description ?

Comment: You're getting that error because the payload you're getting back does not have the path you specified. Your object is basically `{ "error": "..." }`.

Comment: I just modified the query, please review once. It is the error message i'm getting in that specific path.

Answer (score 1):

Your error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value is the string and you try to convert it to JSON to write. Don't convert - write it as it is (already string).

In other words - don't use write - string is already string.

Or, maybe, you need opposite? To change String to JSON? This is more common need and it is done by read function. https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/ChangeStringToJsonOnTheFly.html